# getSelectedItemPosition() always return -1

Tags: android, listactivity

I have a class that extends ListActivity, its work fine

Then in the onListItemClick() I use getSelectedItemPosition() and its always return -1

P.S getSelectedItemId() return some long number like 994393434

```
public class TasksShowActivity  extends ListActivity {

    private Cursor mCursor; 
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    private static final String[] mContent = new String[] {
        TasksDbHelper._ID, TasksDbHelper.NAME,
        TasksDbHelper.USER};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        mCursor = managedQuery(
                TasksProvider.CONTENT_URI, mContent, null, null, null);

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                    R.layout.tasks, mCursor, 
                    new String[] {TasksDbHelper.NAME, TasksDbHelper.USER}, 
                    new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.date});

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, final long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Position: "+this.getSelectedItemPosition() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tasks_root_element">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code, my crystal ball is at the shop today.

Comment: Already use `final long id` from onListItemClick argument list

Comment: Whay don't you use the `position` parameter that is coming in?  No need to use the method... the info is already there.

Answer (score 11):

> Then in the onListItemClick() I use getSelectedItemPosition() and its always return -1

That is because nothing is selected. "Click" and "select" are separate things. "Select" in a `ListView` is done via the pointing device (D-pad, trackball, arrow keys, etc.).