# listView.getSelectedItemPosition() return index-1

Tags: android

I have my custom listview and at the end of each row I have ImageView to delete that row from the list but when I click on this image I get "Arryindesoutofboundexception: length=681 indez=-1"

Help me

```
private OnClickListener imageviewClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      int index;
        index=listView.getSelectedItemPosition();//itemsListView is the listview
        dataAdapter.remove(topicsList.get(index));
        topicsList.clear();
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


  }
};
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723685/getselecteditemposition-always-return-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your item isn't selected because the image intercepts the touch event, therefore the selected position is -1.
In order to make this work you need to tell the OnClickListener what item it belongs to:

```
private static class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private final int mIndex;

    private MyClickListener (int index) {
        mIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dataAdapter.remove(topicsList.get(mIndex));
        topicsList.clear();
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get position of an selected item from a `ListView`, even though there was no item selected. From the docs of [`getSelectedItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29), you can see, that if no item is selected, then it returns the [`INVALID_POSITION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#INVALID_POSITION), which is `-1`.