# Listview not holding selection index

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in single choice mode. When a button is hit, I want to be able to get the selection value of that list view. But, it always returns -1, even when I set the selection in the click listener. What's going on? Am I only able to get this information from the onClick?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reorderlist);


    //setup Adapter to ArrayList of String
    origAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, originalViewingList);

    //set ListView
    origLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.originalPoolList) ;
    origLV.setAdapter(origAdapter);

    //setup selected item
    origLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //save selection index
            origLV.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
}


public void onMoveListDown(View v) {

    // get selected item
    // ?? Returns -1 ??
    int selPos = origLV.getSelectedItemPosition();

 }
```

Here's the Layout XML:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="188dp"
    android:id="@+id/originalPoolList"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:listSelector="#666666"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Edit: To elaborate, I select a item from the listview. And I want to get that selected item's position when I hit MoveList button. That button's onClick is connected to the onMoveListDown. Whenever I hit the first item in the list then the button, the value selPos =-1 instead of 0.

Comment: When do you call onMoveListDown()?

Comment: It's connected to a Button's OnClick()

Comment: Can you show what's going on?

Comment: I added some more detail into the question

Comment: Try setting a private int property like clickedPosition. In the onItemClickListener set this property to position. Can you try that?

Comment: Sure. That would probably work, I'm just more curious as to why I wouldn't be able to grab that int in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered from this similar question:

[listView.getSelectedItemPosition() return index-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060279/listview-getselecteditemposition-return-index-1)

Is that your Button OnClick interrupts the item selection. getSelectedItemPosition() returns -1 if no item is selected. So the fact that you generate another touch event in between handling the selected position interrupts the position, and in fact clears the selection. Causing the getSelectedItemPosition() to return -1.

As I have mentioned in the comments, you could make an int variabele defined in the class scope and saved your selection there, so you can extract it whenever you need it without worrying about the selection getting cleared.

Comment: How can it interrupt the item selection if it is done after the onItemClick has ran? When I step through, it goes through it in order.

Comment: Your button click event (which calls onMoveListDown()) clears the selection. onMoveListEvent() is executed AFTER the button click event, so getSelectedItemPosition() returns -1.

Comment: So, it loses it's selection when it loses focus?

Comment: @sparkysword It loses focus, yes. In a way. A selection, like onItemSelected() is a touch event. You can't select two things at once, so you can't do a button press while selecting a list item. That is why the selection is cleared.

Comment: @sparkysword No problem. If you think the answer well, answers your question I'd appreciate it if you would accept it. :)