# Android ListView SETTING Selected On Button of Item Clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a button inside each item, and configured with:

```
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:listSelector="#AAAAAA"
```

In layout, the onclick of the buttons are defined as onClickItemButton.

GETTING the position of item is working, the problem is SETTING the selected item.

The problem is: If I click a item, outside the button, the item get selected and background color changes. But, if I click the button of the item, the item get deselected!

```
public void onClickItemButton(View view) {
    View item = (View) view.getParent();
    int pos = listView.getPositionForView(item);
    long id = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);

    /* here I try to set the selected item, note that 'pos' is correctly defined*/

    String sel = String.valueOf(listView.getSelectedItemPosition());

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"clicked pos="+String.valueOf(pos)+"selected pos="+sel,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have tried the following codes in /* here I try to set the selected item */

```
    1) listView.setSelection(pos);

    2) listView.setItemChecked(pos,true);

    3)int id = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());
    listView.performItemClick(view,pos,id);
```

But I always get "clicked pos=N selected pos=-1" and no item highlighted (where N is the correct position of clicked item)!!

Comment: I think you need to set the view's tag, using `setTag` (in the adapter's bindView or getView method, say setting it to the position), and then extract the tag, using `getTag` in the onClickItemButton method.

Answer (score 1):

**[getSelectedItemPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)**

> Return the position of the currently selected item within the
>   adapter's data set

You should use this within Listview **onItemClick** Method .

Read **[getSelectedItemPosition() always return -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060279/listview-getselecteditemposition-return-index-1)**

Comment: pos (clicked item) has returned correctly, my problem is not that, is SETTING the selected item... listView.setSelection(pos); listView.setItemChecked(pos,true); etc...