# Why getChildAt returns null in some cases in GridView's onItemClick listener, even if the view is visible

Tags: android

I am trying to surround the selected view with a border , and remove borders from any other views that were selected before , so i am saving the position of every selected view ,then pass it to getChildAtPosition to change its background , unfortunately in some cases -which are random to me- it returns null

I searched and found that in most cases the problem was that the views weren't visible so i tried to check if the view is visible using (getFirst and get Last Visible item) methods, but still doesn't work , beside it returns null even if the two views ( the newly and previously selected) are next to each other
here are the questions i looked at

[listView.getSelectedItemPosition() return index-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060279/listview-getselecteditemposition-return-index-1)

[Sometimes listView.getChildAt(int index) returns NULL (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318862/sometimes-listview-getchildatint-index-returns-null-android)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageView selectedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


//i initialize it with -1
    if(positionIcon != -1){

        parent.getChildAt(positionIcon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_border);

    }
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_icon_border);
    if(selectedImage.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
        selectedIcon = (int) selectedImage.getTag();
    }else{
        selectedUri = selectedImage.getTag().toString();
    }
    positionIcon = position;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_icon_border);

}
```

UPDATE : here are the views which causes the null exception

here is the log 
04-11 15:30:46.054 5723-5723/shobaky.studientsecretary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: shobaky.studientsecretary, PID: 5723
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at shobaky.studientsecretary.MaterialDialog.onItemClick(MaterialDialog.java:345)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:346)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1547)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3827)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5849)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: please share the log

Comment: de-de-de-debugger!

Comment: check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are selecting deselecting(trying to implement something like radio button).
-you can save previously selected view's reference and update when next item tapped.
-try some thing like below....

```
View previouslySelectedView;
```

and  than

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
ImageView selectedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
if(previouslySelectedView != null){
    previouslySelectedView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_border);
}
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_icon_border);
if(selectedImage.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
    selectedIcon = (int) selectedImage.getTag();
}else{
    selectedUri = selectedImage.getTag().toString();
}
positionIcon = position;
previouslySelectedView=view;
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_icon_border);
}
```

Comment: Amazing , nice solution that worked, thanks alot,do you have any idea why my solution didn't work?